How to use MUI X v7 with MUI Core v6?
I encountered the following error when I run npm i:

or in text form:
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @mui/x-date-pickers@7.7.0
npm error Found: @mui/material@6.0.0-alpha.11
npm error node_modules/@mui/material
npm error   @mui/material@"next" from the root project
npm error   peer @mui/material@"^6.0.0-alpha.11" from @mui/icons-material@6.0.0-alpha.11
npm error   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm error     @mui/icons-material@"next" from the root project
npm error   1 more (@mui/material-nextjs)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @mui/material@"^5.15.14" from @mui/x-date-pickers@7.7.0
npm error node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers
npm error   @mui/x-date-pickers@"^7" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @mui/material@5.15.20
npm error node_modules/@mui/material
npm error   peer @mui/material@"^5.15.14" from @mui/x-date-pickers@7.7.0
npm error   node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers
npm error     @mui/x-date-pickers@"^7" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /Users/andrew/.npm/_logs/2024-06-19T17_10_57_488Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/andrew/.npm/_logs/2024-06-19T17_10_57_488Z-debug-0.log

How to use MUI X v7 with MUI Core v6?

I think adding your package.json, npm & node version would help narrowing down the issue

use force command to install run with npm i --force

-force "forces" npm to re-download all packages and install them again. The issue that may arise from that is that obviously if you have too many packages it takes more time to download them each time.

npm install, -force flag

I tried using -force flag, but the UI is distorted
